# ContextMenu in Word

Tags: office-js

Creating a manifest for a Word Add-in. I am trying to put TWO menu items on the ContextMenuText. I am following the guidance here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/control#menu-dropdown-button-controls. Here is where I get this understanding:

> When used with a PrimaryCommandSurface or **ContextMenu** extension point, the menu control defines:
>
> - A root-level menu item.
> - **A list of submenu items**.

Everything I read says this is possible, and when I run NPM VALIDATE, it tells me that my manifest is valid. However, when I try to sideload with NPM START, the taskpane appears with the yellow warning that the manifest was not loaded. Also when I try to sideload in Word Online it tells me that my manifest is invalid.

If I define only a single top level CONTROL as a BUTTON it works fine. But I really need two items on the context menu.

Here is the relevant part of my manifest:

```xml
<!--CONTEXT MENU-->
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="ContextMenu">
<OfficeMenu id="ContextMenuText">
  <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="myMenuId">
    <Label resid="ContextMenu.Label" />
    <Supertip>
        <Title resid="ContextMenu.Label" />
        <Description resid="ContextMenu.ToolTip" />
    </Supertip>   
    <Icon>
      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
    </Icon>    
    <Items>
      <!--FIRST CONTEXT MENU BUTTON-->
      <Item id="firstCtxMenuId">
        <Label resid="FirstButton.Label"/>
        <Supertip>
          <Title resid="FirstButton.Label"/>
          <Description resid="FirstButton.Tooltip"/>
        </Supertip>
        <Icon>
          <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
          <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
          <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
        </Icon>
        <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
          <FunctionName>doThing1</FunctionName>
        </Action>
      </Item>
      <!--SECOND CONTEXT MENU BUTTON-->
      <Item id="secondCtxMenuId"> -->
        <Label resid="SecondButton.Label"/>
        <Supertip>
          <Title resid="SecondButton.Label"/>
          <Description resid="SecondButton.Tooltip"/>
        </Supertip>
        <Icon>
          <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
          <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
          <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
        </Icon>
        <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
          <FunctionName>doThing2</FunctionName>
        </Action>
      </Item>
    </Items>
  </Control>
</OfficeMenu>
```

Is there something wrong with my manifest that I am just not seeing? Or does Word NOT support multiple items on the context menu?

Comment: More weirdness... If I try to sideload in Word online, or Word x86 I get an error. I logged into the Office 365 Admin Portal and added it as a mandatory Organizational Add-in. It was accepted and validated and shows it is available. But when I go to Word Online (or Word x86), it does not load. If I don't make it mandatory but simply available, and then go into Word  Online (or Word x86) and try to add it from Managed Add-ins, an error shows up in Word status bar: "Error loading add-in."

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have not added the relevant resources at the bottom of the manifest file because I don't see them in your code sample. Try reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-addin-commands#step-7-add-the-resources-element) part of the docs more thoroughly, and see if that helps.

Here is a sample manifest I used which accomplishes what I believe you are trying to accomplish:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" 
  xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <Id>18d46177-646b-4767-a5b8-efe907a59a95</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Patent Theory"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="A template to get started."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>contoso.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Document"/>
  </Hosts>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="Document">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <GetStarted>
            <Title resid="GetStarted.Title"/>
            <Description resid="GetStarted.Description"/>
            <LearnMoreUrl resid="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
          </GetStarted>
          <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabHome">
              <Group id="CommandsGroup">
                <Label resid="CommandsGroup.Label"/>
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                </Icon>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="TaskpaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
          <!-- Datajoy New Extension Point -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="ContextMenu">
            <OfficeMenu id="ContextMenuText">
              <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="MarkAsProfanity.Menu">
                <Label resid="MarkAsProfanity.Label" />
                <Supertip>
                  <Title resid="MarkAsProfanity.Label" />
                  <Description resid="MarkAsProfanity.Description" />
                </Supertip>
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                </Icon>
                <Items>
                  <Item id="IgnoreProfanity.Button">
                    <Label resid="IgnoreProfanity.Label"/>
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="IgnoreProfanity.Label" />
                      <Description resid="IgnoreProfanity.Description" />
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                      <FunctionName>ignoreProfanity</FunctionName>
                    </Action>
                  </Item>
                  <Item id="ClaimsAndSpec.Button">
                    <Label resid="ClaimsAndSpec.Label"/>
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="ClaimsAndSpec.Label" />
                      <Description resid="ClaimsAndSpec.Description" />
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                      <FunctionName>markAsClaimsAndSpecProfanity</FunctionName>
                    </Action>
                  </Item>
                  <Item id="Claims.Button">
                    <Label resid="Claims.Label"/>
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="Claims.Label" />
                      <Description resid="Claims.Description" />
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                      <FunctionName>markAsClaimsProfanity</FunctionName>
                    </Action>
                  </Item>
                  <Item id="Spec.Button">
                    <Label resid="Spec.Label"/>
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="Spec.Label" />
                      <Description resid="Spec.Description" />
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                      <FunctionName>markAsSpecProfanity</FunctionName>
                    </Action>
                  </Item>
                </Items>
              </Control>
            </OfficeMenu>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276812"/>
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="Get started with your sample add-in!"/>
        <bt:String id="CommandsGroup.Label" DefaultValue="Commands Group"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane"/>
        <bt:String id="MarkAsProfanity.Label" DefaultValue="Patent Theory"/>
        <bt:String id="ClaimsAndSpec.Label" DefaultValue="Mark in claims and spec"/>
        <bt:String id="Claims.Label" DefaultValue="Mark in claims"/>
        <bt:String id="Spec.Label" DefaultValue="Mark in spec"/>
        <bt:String id="IgnoreProfanity.Label" DefaultValue="Ignore profanity"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="Your sample add-in loaded succesfully. Go to the HOME tab and click the 'Show Taskpane' button to get started."/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show a Taskpane"/>
        <bt:String id="MarkAsProfanity.Description" DefaultValue="Patent Theory"/>
        <bt:String id="ClaimsAndSpec.Description" DefaultValue="Mark in claims and spec"/>
        <bt:String id="Claims.Description" DefaultValue="Mark in claims"/>
        <bt:String id="Spec.Description" DefaultValue="Mark in spec"/>
        <bt:String id="IgnoreProfanity.Description" DefaultValue="Ignore profanity"/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: Actually, my manifest includes the resources element and all the proper elements above as well. I just cut them out of my post for conciseness to focus on the context menu alone. However, reviewing yours to mine I see no differences structurally. Everything should work but it does not.

When I get a chance to revisit this, I will see if maybe it has to do with my version of Office (Insiders Build), or some other issue I am just not seeing right now. For giggles I also will try your manifest in a blank solution and see if it works.