# Word web addin: modification of Context Menu not working with ExtensionPoint xsi:type="ContextMenu"

Tags: office-js, word-web-addins

i am working on word Web Addin and trying to add a button in context menu of word(Right Click Menu). updated Manifest file with ExtensionPoint

as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-addin-commands?source=docs. but menu is not updated. i am using Visual Studio.

Using Office  professional plus 2016.

added below snippet after    node. is there any intialization need to be done. appreciated if any Immediate help

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="ContextMenu">
  <OfficeMenu id="ContextMenuText">
                  <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="TestContextMenu">
      <Label resid="MenuLabel" />
      <Supertip>
        <Title resid="MenuTitle" />
        <Description resid="MenuDescription" />
      </Supertip>
      <Icon>
        <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon1_32x32" />
        <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon1_32x32" />
        <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon1_32x32" />
      </Icon>
      <Items>
        <Item id="ContextMenuItem">
          <Label resid="ContextMenuItemLabel"/>
          <Supertip>
            <Title resid="ContextitemSupertip" />
            <Description resid="MenuDescription" />
          </Supertip>
          <Icon>
            <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
            <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
            <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
          </Icon>
          <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
            <FunctionName>displaySelectedText</FunctionName>
          </Action>
        </Item>
      </Items>
    </Control>
  </OfficeMenu>
</ExtensionPoint>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks similar to my request I submitted yesterday.

[ContextMenu in Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61872534/contextmenu-in-word)

I had found there was some way to get one single control on the submenu, but it stopped working for me after I tried messing with adding more controls that way. I am not sure what I did at first, but it was something like this:

```xml
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="ContextMenu">
  <OfficeMenu id="ContextMenuText">
     <Control xsi:type="Button" id="TestContextMenu">
      <Label resid="MenuLabel" />
      <Supertip>
        <Title resid="MenuTitle" />
        <Description resid="MenuDescription" />
      </Supertip>
      <Icon>
        <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon1_32x32" />
        <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon1_32x32" />
        <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon1_32x32" />
      </Icon>
      <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
          <FunctionName>displaySelectedText</FunctionName>
      </Action>
    </Control>
  </OfficeMenu>
</ExtensionPoint>
```

Comment: Hi David,  i have added single menu item but right click item not appearing whereas my task pane appears fine.  Tried with button type also. may i know your  office desktop version.

Comment: Sorry. I am not sure what I did unfortunately to get it to work. I worked the first time I tried it, I saw that there was only one item so I tried to get two to work and from that point it never worked again.

Comment: I am using Office 365 - Insiders Build. Not sure of the exact version as I am not at that machine right now. I will hopefully be able to get back to this project in coming weeks.